# With lesser DTU we observe better performance on Azure SQL Server with Elastic Standard

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring

**Context:** During recent performance evaluation for our application we observed that with higher DTU's the response time were higher compare to lower DTU's.

**Response Time Trend On the Application Front:**

[image]

**Resource Usage Pattern:**

[image]

Not able to understand why with *higher DTU's* it perform **Under** and with *lower DTU's* it perform **better**. Any suggestions ?

**Current Configuration:**
SQL Server Type: Elastic Standard
SQL Elastic Pool Considered: 400, 300 & 100 DTU's

Note: Checked the Web App usage they are almost identical. We couldn't find any discrepancy there. Also check the SQL-Server Performance there are no indexing issue.

Comment: hard to say without knowing more about your schema and query pattern, but perhaps you have parallel queries on the higher DTU configurations that block more?  I suggest you look at the query store to see more specifically which queries perform better/worse during the time windows in question.

Comment: Yeah it is issue with the parallelism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher service levels allow to higher degree of parallelism and lower service levels limit the the degree of parellism to 1. When you scale up to higher service tiers try limit the degree of parellism to 1.

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 1;
```

Comment: Yeah we evaluated with 400DTU's with MAXDOP to 1 and response time were almost same to 100DTU's . Thank you so much Alberto.

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick Now the database will have more cores available to server other queries and user requests. I am glad it worked for you.